# how to combine multiple csv files into a csv file using tcl

Tags: csv, tcl

I tried to combine all the similar csv files together using TCL

```
exec /bin/cat checked_*.csv > check_all.csv
```

but the result show :

/bin/cat: checked_*.csv: No such file or directory

while executing

"exec /bin/cat checked_*.csv > check_all.csv"
    (file "test.tcl" line 80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm maybe a pure Tcl solution?

```
set files [glob checked_*.csv]
set fout [open "check_all.csv" w]

foreach file $files {
    set fin [open $file r]
    fcopy $fin $fout
    close $fin
}

close $fout
```

EDIT: Swapped `puts $fout [read $fin]` for `fcopy $fin $fout` thanks to glenn jackman.

Comment: the weird thing for my script is that i able to combine all the files if i run in another script that without previous script where i create the checked files and do sth on it. will it affect ? as the result for the code you gave, i only able to write one of the file into the check_all.csv

Comment: @EwOng If the files have not been written yet, then yes, it would make sense that not all files are written to the check_all file.

Comment: You might want to `fcopy $fin $fout` instead of `puts $fout [read $fin]` -- I believe `fcopy` will be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman! Haven't come across this command till you mentioned it

Answer (score 2):

The `exec` command doesn't expand file names like the shell does, so `cat` just receives the string `checked_*.csv`. My guess is that

```
exec /bin/cat {*}[glob checked_*.csv] > check_all.csv
```

would work better (I'm on Windows, though). Tcl 8.5 or later required because of the expansion.

I'd recommend

```
package require fileutil

::fileutil::writeFile check_all.csv [::fileutil::cat {*}[glob -nocomplain checked_*.csv]]
```

by the way.

Comment: What do you get if you run `/bin/cat checked_*.csv > check_all.csv` in the shell?

Comment: /bin/cat: checked_*.csv: No such file or directory

Comment: i think is my previous code affected it. before combining those files, i created them at the same script, will it be the problem?

Comment: No, creating the files in the same script doesn't mean they can't be concatenated into another file. But if that is what you are doing, why aren't you putting all of your data into `check_all.csv` in the first place?

Comment: as i want separated files and combined file

Comment: Then why not write to the separate files and to the combined file at the same time? It's less work.

Answer (score 0):

you need exec with full path of your `*.csv`, like

```
exec /bin/cat /home/s/pathtofile/checked_*.csv > check_all.csv
```

Comment: i still unable to combine it. I think it because in the script, i just create the files and caused it unable to create. is there any solution?

Comment: That won't work. `exec` doesn't expand globs for you.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution: launch a shell to handle the globbing and redirection for you:

```
exec /bin/sh -c {/bin/cat checked_*.csv > check_all.csv}
```